# Assigning a weight to thousands of values in the attribute table to then make a heat map in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, heat-map, weighted-overlay

I am working with some data that has about 19,000 values. This data has been imported as a text delimited file layer, as it is GPS (long and lat) point value data, that has an associated metadata or attribute field "hours". I have plotted the 19,000 points, and am trying to make a heat map based on the number of hours spent at each point. So, when I try the heatmap function and weigh the heat map by "hours" I do not receive the results I want. I understand that I can assign a weight to each of the 19,000 points based on how many hours spent at each point. I.e. The point with the highest amount of hours would be assigned the highest weight.

I have tried the CASE function in the field calculator but since this only works for individual values (as all the numbers of hours are different) and I have 19,000 values, I would like to know if there is a function where I can assign a weight for all 19,000 points based on how many hours spent, and then I can weigh the heat map based on the new attribute (the weights of the hours) that I just created.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting your layer as a shapefile, then make a new field in the attribute table using the "Field Calculator">create a new field. Name your new field whatever you want, and then in the expression box navigate to your hours field (should be under the "Fields and Values" section, and then make a mathematical equation for whatever you want your weighted index to be equal to, say something like if("Hours">4, 10, 0)

Then, go to properties>symbology>Graduated and select your new index field as the value.

Comment: Hi Ian! If my largest value is 9880.940555999999560 and my lowest value is 0, what would my weighted index code look like? Thanks so much!

Comment: Well it really depends on what you are looking for! What values do you want to highlight as "Good" or "Bad"?

Comment: I am just looking to make a heat map where the more hours spent, the more weight they have. I guess you could say the more hours spent is "bad".

Comment: I would then skip the part where you make a new field. Just go into properties in the shapefile>Symbology>Graduated Then select your hours value in the "Value" dropdown, and then click "Classify" which is towards the bottom of the screen. It should automatically split up the hours into categories of coloration which you can change to your own liking if you wish!

Comment: Yes I have done this already, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this same thing but with the heat map feature?

Comment: As in a raster heatmap?

Comment: I am honestly not sure! I am just trying to show the areas with more hours as darker/denser areas on a heat map!

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want your finished product to look like?

Answer (score 0):

the heatmap renderer has a "Weight point by" dropdown list that will let you choose your hour field as weight for your points.

If this didn't give you the result you want you may need to use some function to adapt/normalise your weight range, this could be done by clicking the Ɛ symbol next to the dropdown and using any appropriate function here (note that point with a weight of 0 are not used ie. they won't be visible or have an impact on the heatmap).

[image]